# ColdFusion 10 REST API: How to parse JSON in body of payload

Tags: rest, coldfusion, coldfusion-10

I'm using ColdFusion 10's new build-in RESTful web services feature. When posting data, I'd like to send the payload as JSON in the body of the request.  For example:

```
PUT https://mycompany.com/rest/v1.0/widget/261469 HTTP/1.1
Host: mycompany.com
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 13
Content-Type: application/json

{"foo":"bar"}
```

Once this data is posted through the API, how should I parse and deserialize the JSON data on the server?  Does ColdFusion REST service have a built-in way to do this?  It seems that there is native support to deserialize "form" type (i.e. content-type application/x-www-form-urlencoded) by setting the restargsource attribute on cfargument to "form", but I'm not able to find any examples on how to deserialize JSON data natively. I was hoping for something like restargsource="json", but that doesn't exist.  What is the recommended way to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After a lot of research, it doesn't look like there's a native way for ColdFusion 10's REST API request handler to parse JSON requests automatically for us.  We need to do this manually as follows:

```
<cfset var json = ToString(GetHttpRequestData().content) />
<cfif !IsJSON(json)>
    <cfthrow errorCode="400" type="ArgumentException" message="#"Invalid JSON string: " & json#" />
</cfif>

<cfset var jsonObject = DeserializeJSON(json) />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also try

```
VARIABLES.postJSON = StructNew();
StructInsert(VARIABLES.postJSON, 'parameter1','xxx');
```

then user `#SerializeJSON(VARIABLES.postJSON)#`

Comment: This does not seem to answer the question, which is about *deserializing* not serializing. Can you elaborate?