# Sending data as application/JSON throws error

Tags: rest, coldfusion

I want to send data over the body as `application/json`. This is my request:
[image: Image of request data]

But with that I only get:

> The @FormParam is utilized when the content type of the request entity
>   is not application/x-www-form-urlencoded

[image: Image of error]

My Code:

```
<cffunction name="createInstance" access="remote" returntype="any" produces="application/json" httpmethod="POST" restpath="/instances">
   <cfargument name="customerId" required="true" restArgSource="form" type="string" default=""/>
   <cfargument name="name" required="true" restArgSource="form" type="string" default=""/>
   <cfargument name="datasource" required="false" restArgSource="form" type="string" default=""/>
   <cfargument name="startDate" required="true" restArgSource="form" type="string" default=""/>
   <cfargument name="expirationDate" required="false" restArgSource="form" type="string" default=""/>
   <cfargument name="amount" required="true" restArgSource="form" type="numeric" default=-1/>

   <cfreturn name>
</cffunction>
```

Comment: To make it clear: you post JSON data to your REST API and expect the members to be available as arguments. True?

Comment: Yes thats the plan

Comment: I think you need to add returnformat="JSON" to your function, by default its WDDX or XML, can you add this attribute and try?

Also you are returning just name filed, please change it to arguments in your cfreturn tag

Comment: @dewey, Did you add *content-type* as *application/json* in header sections.? Seems you have 9 values in header section. So please check that where you have content-type or not.

Comment: @Keshavjha That doesn't make any difference if I add this to my function parameters.

Comment: @Kannan.P I've tried that, also no difference :(

Comment: `cffunction` has a `consumes` attribute. Try to set it `consumes="application/json"`

Comment: @BernhardDöbler Sadly made no difference either..

Comment: I think we need to see the code you’re using to make the http post request.

Comment: There's this 6 years old answer that said it's not how it's supposed to work: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15819813/577052

Comment: Adam Cameron had it in 2013 - your function is supposed to have one argument of type struct: http://blog.adamcameron.me/2013/05/passing-complex-object-to-coldfusion.html

Comment: @dewey Please check with your **restArgSource** attributes. You used form which mean **Extracts parameters from a form submission. It is used with HTTP POST method**.  But you are not going to use any form data here. That's may be causes of your issues.

Comment: @Kannan.P I know that this is not a valid attribute for my usage. But none of the restArgSource arguments worked in my case.

Comment: @dewey What version of CF are you running? Could it be affected by this bug? https://tracker.adobe.com/#/view/CF-4158293

Comment: It seems that the code receiving the json expects an application/x-www-form-urlencoded content.

Answer (score 0):

Usually the JSON handlers should be used as GET method. Can you try with httpmethod as GET and restArgSource as path.

```
<cffunction name="createInstance" 
    access="remote" 
    returntype="any" 
    produces="application/json" 
    httpmethod="GET" 
    restpath="/instances">

  <cfargument name="customerId" required="true" 
         restArgSource="Path" type="numeric" />
```

If you still need the request as POST, can you please share the headers tab?